# Don't know how to change text colors in VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Ok so basically I'm trying to change the color theme of the text editor for the code. I write in c++ and I saw a "palette" online that I really like : [The colors I would like to apply somehow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSSMd.png)

But my text isn't like that and when I write comments it's green which I really don't like. Like this: [The colors on my text editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcvwH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the display colours (as well as fonts, sizes and many other characteristics) via the `Options` command from the `Tools` menu.

Select/Expand the `Environment` node in the left-hand panel of the displayed dialog box, then select `Fonts and Colors`. It *should* look something like this:

[image]

You can select colours for individual `C`/`C++` syntax elements. by scrolling through the list in the `Display Items` list (there are quite a number of them).

*Note: This is the system for Visual Studio 2019; other versions may be slightly different, but the general principle should hold true.*

Alternatively, you may like to try the [Visual Studio Color Theme Designer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-madsk.ColorThemeDesigner) - but I don't use this and haven't tested it.